# How do I get my 12 IF formula to work in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test
    Range(“A1:A” & FR).Formula =“=If(mid(h1,4,1)=“”C””,””1/“”&Mid(h1,5,2)&””/2020””,If(mid(h1,4,1)=“”D””,””2/“”&Mid(h1,5,2)&””/2020”,If(Mid(h1,4,1)=“”E””,””3/“”&mid(h1,5,2)&””/2020””,)))
End sub
```

My formula goes all the way out to 12 if statements ending with the 12th month at letter N. Would it be more suitable in vba to use an if then else statement?

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: First get your formula working in the cell manually. Then copy it into VBA and double all quotes `"` within the formula itself.

Comment: A runtime error occurs when I run the code but when I put the formula in the cell manually it doesn’t work because it’s greater than 7 If statements. If I just use 7 it will work.

Comment: @Djh006 it might be helpful to specify _which_ RTE, instead of just "a"...

Comment: @Djh006 what _version_ of Excel are you using? Older version are limited to 7 levels of nesting as Pᴇʜ mentioned...

Comment: What's your formula trying to do?  It looks overly complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function ConvertDate(r as range) as string
dim d as string
d = Mid(r,5,2) & "/2020"
select case mid(r,4,1)
case "C"
       ConvertDate = "1/" & d
case "D"
       ConvertDAte = "2/" & d
....etc...

end select
end function
```

Then your code becomes

```
Sub Test
Range(“A1:A” & FR).Formula = "=ConvertDate($H$1)"
end sub
```

Comment: When I put this function above my code it returns a #Name error in the cell

Comment: Have you put all the case statements in? - I didn't do the one's after D, you'll need to work through the other ten. One other possibility is that this needs to be in a standard module, not the module attached to a sheet or workbook.

Comment: How would I change the variable to d to have the year change automatically when it is a new year so I don’t have to go in and change it manually?

Comment: d=mid(r,5,2) & "/" & year(date)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a double quote mark before the last `,If(Mid(h1,4,1)`

```
Range("A1:A" & FR).Formula = "=If(mid(h1,4,1)=""C"",""1/""&Mid(h1,5,2)&""/2020"",If(mid(h1,4,1)=""D"",""2/""&Mid(h1,5,2)&""/2020"",If(Mid(h1,4,1)=""E"",""3/""&mid(h1,5,2)&""/2020"",)))"
```

Comment: Fixed my quotes and it still gives me a runtime error.

Comment: @Djh006 What is `FR` defined as? You omitted it from your original question - assumed it was a `Long` and set it equal to 3 in my test

Comment: I used the public function code that @harassed dad gave but I am getting a #Name? Error when I run the code.

Answer (score 0):

Excel versions below Excel 2010 don't support more than 7 nested functions in formulas.

See [CPearson: Nested Functions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/nested.htm)

> As a general "rule of thumb," if you have a formula with more than 7 nested statements, you should consider using a VBA function instead.

Comment: As of Excel 2010, they increased the nesting level to 64 (IIRC). _However_, just because you _can_ does **not** mean you _should_.

Comment: @FreeMan Thanks for the follow up. Didn't know that changed. Nevertheless the OP might have used an old Excel version here (since it worked with 7 but not with more).

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, I'm glad you told me :) I thought this would still be a limit